# ngFor not working angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to display some data from server in my component.

```
export class CommerceComponent implements OnInit {

     dealList;

    ngOnInit() {
         this.getDeals();
     }

    getDeals(){
    this.gatewayService.searchDeals(this.searchParams).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        this.dealList = data.result;
        console.log("Deal list",this.dealList[0]);
      },
      (error)=>{
         console.log("Error getting deal list",error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Service

```
searchDeals(data){

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('token',this.cookieService.get('token'));
        fd.append('search',data.keyword);

        return this.http.post(config.url+'hyperledger/queryByParams',fd);

    }
```

In html

```
<div class="deal1" *ngFor="let deal of dealList">
  {{deal.Deal.title}}
 </div>
```

But the list is not rendering, however, I am getting `console.log("Deal list",this.dealList[0]);` single object and `this.dealList` return array of objects

Comment: try to do the same thing in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: first check your dealList with passing static data and check whether its rendering

Comment: same thing means

Comment: @AbineshJoyel this `dealList =[1,2];` this render the list properly

Comment: same thing means same call to `getDeals` function just do it in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of doing it in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: @iambatman can i know your format of json data the format of `this.dealList[0]`

Comment: Here is the whole https://pastebin.com/11zHh6Tt

Comment: If you use typescript, It's highly recommended to specific `dealList` data type. it prevents this types of type mistakes. You just should make sure `dealList` is an array

Comment: are doing this on a modular way? like you have multiple modules?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the result in `this.dealList[0]`, you need also to iterate over `[0]` indexed item.

```
<div class="deal1" *ngFor="let deal of dealList[0]">
   {{deal.title}}
</div>
```

But your `dealList` is undefined, so accessing `[0]` will throw an exception. You need to initialize it as well

```
dealList = []
```

Comment: this.dealList[0] populate single object and this.dealList getting array of objects

Answer (score 0):

The title you wanted to display is located `result[i].Deal.title`

Here is the image of your JSON response .

[image]

```
<div class="deal1" *ngFor="let deal of dealList">
    {{deal.Deal.title}}
</div>
```